# Flask - Unsupported method ('GET')

Tags: python-2.7, methods, get, flask

I just installed flask 0.10.1, and try out sample:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` result is:

> Error response Error code 501. Message: Unsupported method ('GET'). 
>   Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation.

I tried uninstall-install flask again, reset machine, nothing works. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])`

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. i think problem is in your installation. better give a try in [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Yes, I added that line 2, but doesn't work. Tested on other machine and everything is fine so I agree with you - it must be installation issue. Thank you for you time :-D

Comment: You have a *different* server (not Flask) already bound to port 5000. Run Flask on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 'methods' keyword argument to the app.route() call, like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

otherwise flask doesn't know which methods this endpoint supports

Comment: I tried that to, it wont work and I don't know why. I use django now. Thank you for your time anyway :)